# How to connect Node SDK to chaincode dev mode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

Following these instructions:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/chaincode-docker-devmode

I am able to successfully use `peer invoke` cli commands in devmode, however the sample Node.js code assumes it deployed with gateway and wallet and hits a first-network connection profile: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/query.js

Is there a way I can change the Node.js code to hit the chaincode devmode instead so I can test more end-to-end?

Comment: well by dev mode if you mean a single peer configuration,You could switch back to basic network.Source code for the same is available in previous version of fabric samples.

Answer (score 0):

Update the "connection.json" file to point to the correct network. Read more about configuring "connection.json" in the [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/connectionprofile.html)

Comment: Well for example the CA doesn't exist in devmode? It's just a peer, chaincode container, cli, so how to connect the Node SDK wallet/user to it if there's no CA to point to?